# Cannot creating folders with php

Tags: php, mkdir

i used the manual from php.net but i cannot get it to work. Don't see what i am doing wrong. I get this error message when i try to do

```
Warning: ftp_mkdir(): Can't create directory: No such file or directory in /home/user/public_html/management/test.php on line 11
There was a problem while creating /home/user/public_html/images/screenshots/wiiu/alien_isolation/
```

below is the code i use...

```
        <?php

        $ftp_user_name = "user";
        $ftp_user_pass = "password";
        $ftp_server = "www.site.com";
        $gamename = "alien_isolation";
        $path = "/home/user/public_html/images/screenshots/wiiu/" . $gamename . "/";
        $conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server);
        $login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass);

        if (ftp_mkdir($conn_id, $path)) {
         echo "successfully created $path\n";
        } else {
         echo "There was a problem while creating $path\n";
        } 

        ftp_close($conn_id); 

        ?>
```

edit: my php handler is set to DSO and now it works

Comment: make sure you have permission to create a folder

Comment: Just to test it, change the permissions on the php file to 667 (this may not be the permissions you want to use in the long run, but it will tell you if that's what's wrong or not)

Comment: Changing the permissions did not change the error message

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the path

```
/home/user/public_html/images/screenshots/wiiu/
```

exists?

Comment: Even if it doesn't exist, `ftp_mkdir();` will create the directory if the php file has proper permissions to do so.

Comment: Ok, didn't know that `ftp_mkdir()` is recursive.

Answer (score 0):

Set the php handler to DSO and it works

Answer (score 0):

```
**Use this** 

<?php
        $ftp_user_name = "user";
        $ftp_user_pass = "password";
        $ftp_server = "www.site.com";
        $gamename = "alien_isolation";
        $path = "/home/user/public_html/images/screenshots/wiiu/";
        $conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server);
        $login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass);
        @ftp_chdir($conn_id, $path);
        if (ftp_mkdir($conn_id, $gamename)) {
         echo "successfully created $path\n";
        } else {
         echo "There was a problem while creating $path\n";
        } 

        ftp_close($conn_id); 

        ?>
```